# Embed Reddit Video with Sound

Tags: api, embed, reddit

I'm trying to embed Reddit videos with sound from a url. So far I've figured out that you can get the a soundless video by doing:

1. Link is https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/jien07/living_the_good_life/
2. Go to https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/jien07/living_the_good_life.json
3. Find fallback_url, in this case it's https://v.redd.it/4ymh7g5fzfv51/DASH_720.mp4

The issue is that that video doesn't have any sound, how can I get it with sound? I've tried doing share->embed, but the code it gives me doesn't work when I put it into a page. It also has more information than I need, I just need the video.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there were some bugs with reddit embed video for a while, the console shows the error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null`, it's because the iframe script can not access the localStorage, `localStorage` will be `null`, but reddit does not handle `null` case:

```js
RedditVideoPlayer.prototype._prepareLocalStorage = function() {
    if (typeof localStorage != "undefined") {
        var e = localStorage.getItem(this.storageNamespace + ".volume") || this.options.volume
          , t = localStorage.getItem(this.storageNamespace + ".muted") || this.options.muted;
        this._lastVolume = parseFloat(e),
        t.toString().toLowerCase() == "true" ? this.mute() : this.unmute()
    }
}
```

There are also some posts on Reddit like point the problem: https://www.reddit.com/r/bugs/comments/jhx80w/embed_imagevideo_code_is_broken/, but there is no response by the official.

I also found that the iframe works on the mobile, because they don't enable the localStorage at the mobile device.

For PC now, you can use the reddit dash url instead of a cross origin proxy in your site.

Answer (score 0):

I found where to get the video with sound. Although this is an old question, some may still stumble upon it.

you should to take it out

```
secure_media.reddit_video.hls_url
```

If you insert this url in the browser, it will download. But if in the player, then everything will be ok! video with sound